# Selecting Objects from NSArray for further deleting with an IBAction

Tags: objective-c, arrays, select

So I am trying to select objects from my array, to be able to delete them when I do an IBAction. I tried:

checking if the item is Selected:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (self.editEnabled) {


    RDNote *selectedNote = [self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (selectedNote.isSelected) {
        selectedNote.selected = NO;
        for (NSIndexPath *indexPathFromArray in self.indexPathsOfSelectedCells) {
            if (indexPathFromArray.row == indexPath.row) {
                [self.mutableCopy removeObject:indexPathFromArray];
            }
        }
    } else {
        selectedNote.selected = YES;
        [self.indexPathsOfSelectedCells addObject:indexPath];
    }
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
```

IBAction:

```
    - (IBAction)didTapTrashBarButton:(id)sender {
NSMutableArray *mutableNotes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.notes];
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in self.indexPathsOfSelectedCells) {
    [mutableNotes removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
self.notes = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableNotes];

[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithArray:self.indexPathsOfSelectedCells]];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    self.indexPathsOfSelectedCells = nil;
    [self activateEditMode:NO];
    [self saveDataToFile:self.notes];
}];
```

}

But I am having issues with indexes e.g.:(some times shows me the Error that Object index 2 is not between [0..1]), and there are bugs while selecting multiple Object and Deleting them.
Please help me with an advice for some other method that I can use, a Code will be perfect! Thanks!

Comment: What is `indexPath.row` in the `IBAction`?  You are passed a UI object in IBActions, not index paths.

Comment: Use CoreData instead of mutableCopy.

Comment: I am new to Objective please give me a link with some example, thanks!

Comment: Your model seems have a `selected` state (well done), so why bother keeping an array of selected items as well?  That's just more to go wrong, and the likely cause (though I haven't studied the code very much).

Comment: @trojanfoe cause I had a bug: after deleting selected items, the las object was reappearing as the first Object

Comment: I'd say ditch that `indexPathsOfSelectedCells`, delete this question and start a new one to solve that bug.  That bug (BTW) is probably just you enumerating an array you are mutating; a classic error.

Comment: @DumitruRogojinaru Is there any issue in provided solution? you accepted the solution and then rolled back.

Comment: @ShehzadAli i've got problems in performing Batches... trying to solve them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem arrises because:
Let say you have five objects in array 1,2,3,4,5

you are running a loop for removing object based on indexpath which are selected rows. Now your indexpath contains 1st row and 3rd row.

while executing it for the first time you will remove object 1. Now 2,3,4,5 will left in the array. Now second time your indexpath.row is 3rd. It will remove third object which is 4 but in actual array it was 3.

Your code is crashing sometimes because if you have selected first row and last row. In this case i have selected 1 and 5. Now my indexpaths array will say I have to delect objectsAtIndexes 1 and 5.

While executing the loop I'll remove object at Index 1. Now i will be left with 2,3,4,5. On second iteration it will say remove objectAtIndex 5 where as Index 5 doesn't exist because now we have 4 elements in array.

In such cases best way of doing this is try removing elements in array from the end like remove 5th element first and then go for other one. Run your loop in reverse order.

```
NSInteger i = [self.indexPathsOfSelectedCells count]-1;

while (i > 0){
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.indexPathsOfSelectedCells objectAtIndex:i];
    [mutableNotes removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    i--;
}
```